# Why does the starting directory matter when launching a OpenGL executable?

Tags: c++, powershell, opengl, shader, executable

I am doing a openGL porject and readering my shaders from .vert and .frag glsl files. I am using CMake with an extension for auto ninja file generation as well. This is my readfile code:

```
std::string readFile(const char *filePath) {
    std::string content;
    std::ifstream fileStream(filePath, std::ios::in);

    if(!fileStream.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not read file " << filePath << ". File does not exist." << std::endl;
        return "";
    }

    std::string line = "";
    while(!fileStream.eof()) {
        std::getline(fileStream, line);
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }

    fileStream.close();
    return content;
}
```

I spent a long time thinking I was crazy because from my build dir I was doing ./app/NAME_OF_APP.exe but the shaders were not being applied just black. It was only when I clicked on it from within the file explorer that it worked so I cd'ed into build/app/ and called ./NAME_OF_APP.exe and boom it worked. Why is this behavior happening? does the starting dir effect the relative pathing of the actual application? seems odd to me. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run a program from a command line the current directory is whatever directory is current in that command prompt. If you run a program from explorer the current directory is the directory that houses the executable.

You could use a function like GetModuleFileName (with NULL as the hModule parameter) to get the path to the executable and then chop off at the last \ and then change to that directory and then the program would not depend on the directory the program is run from.

Comment: Or you could put the other files inside the .exe, perhaps by using windows resources